# Correct way to unit test the type of an object

Tags: c#, .net, vs-unit-testing-framework

Using the Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework, I'm looking at two options:

```
Assert.AreEqual(myObject.GetType(), typeof(MyObject));
```

and

```
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(myObject, typeof(MyObject));
```

Is there a difference between these two options? Is one more "correct" than the other?

What is the standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The first example will fail if the types are not exactly the same while the second will only fail if `myObject` is not assignable to the given type e.g.

```
public class MySubObject : MyObject { ... }
var obj = new MySubObject();

Assert.AreEqual(obj.GetType(), typeof(MyObject));   //fails
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(obj, typeof(MyObject));     //passes
```

Answer (score 12):

looks XUnit is better:

```
Assert.IsType<MyClass>(myObj);
```

Answer (score 11):

Minor syntactical point: while the above `Assert.AreEqual()` statements will work, the order of the parameters should be reversed, i.e., `Assert.AreEqual(Type expected, Type actual)`.

So, in this case: `Assert.AreEqual(typeof(MyObject), obj.GetType());`

Answer (score 7):

In NUnit

`Assert.That(myObject, Is.TypeOf<MyObject>()) //Tests exact type`

and

`Assert.That(myObject, Is.InstanceOf<MyObject>()) //Tests type and subtype`

Easiest asserts to understand because of naming that NUnit followed :)

Answer (score 4):

In my case it works fine with next line:

```
Assert.IsAssignableFrom<TheClass>(result);
```